# Excel IF AND formula between two times

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to have a formula which will tell me if a time in a cell is between 2 separate vlaues in other cells and to return a value if so.

I have already created the below code but this is not returning any values back at all.

```
=IF(AND(F4>=$R$1,F4<P1),"Night Shift",IF(AND(F4>=$P$1,F4<$Q$1),"AM Shift",IF(AND(F4>=$Q$1,F4<$R$1),"PM Shift","")))
```

In this example the cell values are (P1 = 06:00, Q1 = 14:00, R1 = 22:00). The value in the F4 is 00:31:38.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first `AND` needs to adjust a little.

Excel sees TIME as a fraction of 1 whole day.  So `00:31:38` though you meant it to be the next day from `22:00`, Excel does not know that and as such will not see it greater than `22:00`

We also do not need to test for the Night Shift.  It is the only option left if the time is not in one of the others:

```
=IF(F4<>"",IF(AND(F4>=$P$1,F4<$Q$1),"AM Shift",IF(AND(F4>=$Q$1,F4<$R$1),"PM Shift","Night Shift")),"")
```

[image]

---

You could also create a small table like such:

```
0            6:00       14:00       22:00
Night Shift AM Shift    PM Shift    Night Shift
```

Then use a HLOOKUP to return the correct value:

```
=HLOOKUP(F4,O1:R2,2,TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: @ Scott Craner - The first option still needs some tweeking. It always returns Night Shift. Try this: `=IF(OR(F4<$P$1,F4>$R$1),"Night Shift",IF(AND(F4>=$P$1,F4<$Q$1),"AM Shift",IF(AND(F4>=$Q$1,F4<$R$1),"PM Shift","")))` – Marco Vos 8 mins ago

Comment: That's even better;-)

Answer (score 2):

I took a slightly different path that Scotts.

- A *Night Shift* occurs if the time is greater or equal to 10PM, **OR** is less than 6AM.
  `=OR($F$4<$P$1,$F$4>=$R$1)`
- An *AM Shift* occurs when the time is greater or equal to 6AM, **AND** is less than 2PM.
  `=AND($F$4>=$P$1,$F$4<$Q$1)`
- A *PM Shift* occurs when the time is greater or equal to 2PM, **AND** is less than 10PM.
  `=AND($F$4>=$Q$1,$F$4<$R$1)`

Stick the three conditions together and you have:

```
=IF(OR($F$4<$P$1,$F$4>=$R$1),"Night Shift",IF(AND($F$4>=$P$1,$F$4<$Q$1),"AM Shift",IF(AND($F$4>=$Q$1,$F$4<$R$1),"PM Shift","")))
```

**Edit**
During testing I entered *00:00:00* in `A1` and `=A1+TIMEVALUE("00:01:00")` in `A2:A1440`.
At *06:00:00*, *14:00:00* and *22:00:00* the changeover in shift happened a minute later.
If, however, I manually typed in *06:00:00* the changeover happened on the hour.  This seems to be because `TIMEVALUE` is calculating 6AM as *0.2499999* rather than *0.25*.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(OR(HOUR(NOW())>22,HOUR(NOW())<7),"NIGHT","")&IF(AND(HOUR(NOW())>6,HOUR(NOW())<15),"MORNING","")&IF(AND(HOUR(NOW())>14,HOUR(NOW())<23),"LATE","")
```

I know a bit late but simplifies everything without the need of using other cells (note there are different times used).
Night - 23-07
AM - 07-15
PM - 15-23