# google-sheets-if-and-formula-between-two-times return result or return original result

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ke5zx1stRv2SRx4aYt9XgM44YNzwKR4RZTh9lymuMFA/edit?usp=sharing)

I need to show the result of altering energy use during peak price times on the cost of energy over the year. To do this I want to change the amount of energy being used, value in G6 to be 8 if the time at B6 is between the morning or afternoon peak pricing times, or keep the value in C6 if B6 is not within the peak pricing times.

Morning Peak Start 06:30:00     Finish 07:45:00
Afternoon Peak Start 16:30:00       Finish 23:45:00

I have attempted to modify the code found here:
[excel-if-and-formula-between-two-times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51194063/excel-if-and-formula-between-two-times)

`=IF(and(B6>$N$3,B6<$O$3),"8",IF(AND(B6>=$P$3,B6<$Q$3),8,C6))`

however, this does not return "8" in the desired time ranges.
You can see in the Google Spreadsheet that I have experimented with code in N6,N7 and N8.

I appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Please examine your cells N3 and P3. They have an extra `05/01/1900` in them. Remove that, leaving the time part, and it should work fine.

The problem is that you were doing a comparison on a time string, e.g. `06:45:00` and a full date string, e.g. `05/01/1900 06:30:00`, which results in a faulty comparison.

Comment: A sneaky hidden date in N3 and P3 that only showed when clicked on. I removed these as you recommended and - wallah - fixed. Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 0):

The values you analyse in a comparison must have the same data type and must have a consistent data within this data type. In your case both `B6`, `N3`,`O3`,`P3` and `Q3` are set to the data type `Time`. However, you are using the format `Date Time` in all the cells but `B3`. As you want to compare dates with time you must set all of these cells with the data type `Date Time`.

To do so, in your Spreadsheet's menu bar, after selecting all these cells select **Format->Number->Date Time** and add the right date to `B6`.